# Product of multiplicative group, as cyclic groups.

Tags: group-theory

Write $f(720)$ as product of cyclic groups. Where $f(n)$ represents the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$.

Attempt: The prime factorization of 720 is $720 = 2^4 \times 3^2 \times 5$. 
So using the theorem: "Let $n = p_1^{m_1}\dots p_k^{m_k}$ be the prime factorization of $n$. Then $f(n)$ is isomorphic to $f(p_1^{m_1})\times\dots\times  f(p_k^{m_k})$. So $f(720) = f(2^4) \times f(3^2) \times f(5) = f(16) \times f(9) \times f(5)$.

Is this correct? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean that $f(n)$ represents the multiplicative group *of integers modulo* $n$:

<strike>No, that is not correct. The multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$ consists only of positive integers less than $n$ that are also relatively prime to $n$. There most there could be is $n-1$, which occurs when $n$ is prime. Since $720$ is very much not prime, it's easy to see that your answer has far too many elements.</strike>

If you are talking about some other multiplicative group, you might want to edit your question to clarify that.

Yes, you are correct, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem (again unless I'm misinterpreting your question).

Comment: So when would the above theorem be able to apply?

Comment: That's the Chinese Remainder Theorem, isn't it? I think I've just given you a false answer

Comment: No it is not. The Chinese Remainder Theorem says if k1,k2,...,ks are relative prime natural numbers, and x1,x2,...,xs are integers, there exists an integer x such that x = xi(mod ki) for 1 <= i <= s.

Comment: See here, near the bottom of the section
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement

Comment: In other news, $f(n)$ is incredibly weird notation to use for the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$. Do me a solid and don't write that again, would you?

Comment: I don't know how to write phi. I don't know the code. Math does not use the same notation. A variable can be anything!

Comment: In math we use the notation $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to denote integers mod $n$. Do you mean the [totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function) by \$\phi\$?
Variables can be anything, but learning the standard notation is an important part of being able to be understood.